# CQL: changing specific data within a user-defined type

Tags: cassandra, cql, user-defined-types

I'm new to CQL; I've been experimenting with UDT's and came across this problem:

Once I've created a user defined type and added a new row to the table, is there any way to update the fields within without having to redefine all of them? For example, I have a table called test consisting of a name ( text, primary key) and a user defined type of the following format:

```
create type favorites(
color text,
number int,
food text,
location set<text>
);
```

I insert a new value into the table as follows:

```
insert into test(name, favorite_stuff) values(
'Spongebob',
{color:'yellow', number: 12, food:'krabby patty', location:{'bikini bottom', 'goo lagoon'}}
);
```

Now, I'd like to change Spongebob's favorite color to 'pink' and add 'glove world' to his list of favorite locations. The only way I know how to do this now is to literally redefine everything:

```
update test 
set favorite_stuff = {
color:'pink',
number:12,
food:'krabby patty',
location:{'bikini bottom', 'goo lagoon', 'glove world'}
} where name='Spongebob';
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your table schema is as `CREATE TABLE test(name text primary key, favorite_stuff frozen<favorites>);`. favorite_stuff **must be frozen** as non-frozen UDTs with nested non-frozen collections are not supported in cassandra. With this schema, you can not do any partial update due to below reason.

> A frozen value serializes multiple components into a single value. Non-frozen types allow updates to individual fields. Cassandra treats the value of a frozen type as a blob. The entire value must be overwritten.

However, you can change your favorites type schema as per below. Then you will be able to update individual atribute (but not location attribute as location is frozen now)

```
create type favorites(
    color text,
    number int,
    food text,
    location frozen<set<text>>
);


cqlsh:test> update test set favorite_stuff.color='pink' where name='Spongebob';
cqlsh:test> select * from test;

 name      | favorite_stuff
-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Spongebob | {color: 'pink', number: 12, food: 'krabby patty', location: {'bikini bottom', 'goo lagoon'}}

(1 rows)
cqlsh:test>
```